# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: python

I want to get a histogram of the raw digits data in 784 dimensions. 
Here is my code:

```
import sys,os
from math import *
import random
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datasets

waitForEnter=False
def exampleDistance(x1, x2):
    dist = 0.
    for i,v1 in x1.iteritems():
        v2 = 0.
        if x2.has_key(i): v2 = x2[i]
        dist += (v1 - v2) * (v1 - v2)
    for i,v2 in x2.iteritems():
        if not x1.has_key(i):
            dist += v2 * v2
    return sqrt(dist)

def computeDistances(data):
    #N = len(data)
    #D = len(data[0])
    N, D = data.shape
    dist = []
    for n in range(N):
        for m in range(n):
            dist.append( exampleDistance(data[n],data[m])  / sqrt(D))
    return dist
Dims = [784]
#Cols = ['#FF0000', '#880000', '#000000', '#000088', '#0000FF']
Cols = ['#FF0000']
Bins = arange(0, 1, 0.02)


plt.xlabel('distance / sqrt(dimensionality)')
plt.ylabel('# of pairs of points at that distance')
#plt.title('dimensionality versus uniform point distances')
plt.title('dimensionality versus digits data point distances')

for i,d in enumerate(Dims):
    distances = computeDistances(datasets.DigitData.X)
    print "D=%d, average distance=%g" % (d, mean(distances) * sqrt(d))
    plt.hist(distances,
             Bins,
             histtype='step',
             color=Cols[i])
    if waitForEnter:
        plt.legend(['%d dims' % d for d in Dims])
        plt.show(False)
        x = raw_input('Press enter to continue...')


plt.legend(['%d dims' % d for d in Dims])
plt.savefig('fig.pdf')
plt.show()
```

But there is something wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HW3.py", line 56, in <module>
    distances = computeDistances(datasets.DigitData.X)
  File "HW3.py", line 39, in computeDistances
    dist.append( exampleDistance(data[n],data[m])  / sqrt(D))
  File "HW3.py", line 23, in exampleDistance
    for i,v1 in x1.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Besides, here is the digit datasets:

```
class DigitData:
    Xall,Yall = loadDigitData('data/1vs2.all')
    N,D = Xall.shape
    N0 = int(float(N) * 0.5)
    X = Xall[0:N0,:]
    Y = Yall[0:N0]
    Xte = Xall[N0:,:]
    Yte = Yall[N0:]
```

Then how can I fix it? As a python beginner, I'm very confused of plotting.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading this [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906394/numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-read?rq=1) and if you still did not find your answer comment on this. I hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know iteritems() is used for dictionary not array.However, the function def exampleDistance(x1, x2): is given by Prof. She let us to use this function to calculate distance. I think I have to minimize the changing in exampleDistance(x1, x2), but I don't know how to do it?

Comment: can you try changing `iteritems` with `items` in your function, change it to `for i,v1 in x1.items()` ?

Comment: Assuming you have a dictionary with keys,, try `for i, v1 in enumerate(x1.iteritems(),1):` . This should do the trick. Here `1` is setting the index to start from 1.